# Resolve string property in spring import resource?

Tags: spring, properties, config

I'd like to be able to include a specific spring configuration file to the application context. I'd like it to be dynamic. How to do this? I'm trying with importing a file with a placeholder in it, for instance:

```
classpath*:config/${config.version}.xml
```

Yet I always get the error that it cannot be resolved, no matter what I do. I noticed that spring resolves properties only after all config are read. How to do it then?

Comment: Take a look at this http://detailfocused.blogspot.com/2010/04/wildcards-in-spring-application-context.html You can replace the version with some identifier in the file name. E.g. : appContext-current.xml and add the new and rename the old one.

Comment: Yeah but I want it to be dynamic... Maven-profile-based. I have different names for each xml config file.

Comment: This is in other (master) xml application context, right? Try <beans profile="dev"><import resource="classpath:dev-config.xml" /></beans> <beans profile="qa"><import resource="classpath:qa-config.xml" /></beans>

Comment: Yes, there is one master context which I would like to include one of many contexts. So those profiles can be switched from maven-level? I was aware of their existance but only in annotation form...

Comment: Yes just build with mvn clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: Also I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581151/how-can-i-use-maven-profile-id-value-in-spring-bean-files , see Wilhelm Kleu's answer