# How does one use a Maven profile?

Tags: java, maven

I  am new to maven and read bit about profiles at this and other resources

What i understood we use profile if we want to do override some default values or do some specific stuff.

In my legacy project i can see below profile where i just see overriding app.mode property. But i do not see using this property
further any where in build. I am sure what special being done here?

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <app.mode>dev</app.mode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Following the comments your problem is not in the pom but in your spring configuration. Have a look on the copy-replace/filter features of mvn to get you `app.mode` in your spring config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile would be *activated* if you pass -Pdev on the command line to Maven.

```
mvn -Pdev
```

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html.

What this profile does is change the setting of the property `app.mode` from whatever it was before to `dev`. You will want to search your pom file (and the poms of any modules) for uses of `$[app.mode}` to see what's happening -- if anything.

Maven properties do not pass into Spring automatically, but it's not uncommon to find configuration in to re-export them as system properties to make them visible to Spring. This typically happens in the configuration for surefire and failsafe, but it's explicit, you'll still see `${app.mode}` in a pom somewhere.

Comment: @ bmargilies Actually i know how it gets activated but i am not getting what we we doing special with this profile

Comment: you mean to say that i need to search for ${app.mode} in pom file. Right? If yes i did not find usage of ${app.mode} in pom file. But yes i can see its used in spring.xml file. But i am wondering can pom supply paramater to spring ?

Comment: Yes, I further clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Maven profiles can be configured however you want them to be. Here are some use cases:

a) The project has several developers. For political and religious reasons, some of the developers are using Windows and some are using Linux. The team develops two profiles, one for Linux and one for Windows, setting project root paths, temporary folder paths, support program paths. These variables are injected into the dependency-calculation process, and subordinate processes that need this information. These profile settings are put into the settings.xml file for each programmer.

b) One of the developers is on loan to the project for a week. She doesn't want to reconfigure her computer for the project standard directory layout, etc., so she creates her own settings.xml that allows her to work in her own root directory.

c) The project uses a continuous integration server, such Hudson or Jenkins. The CI needs to have its own database for integration testing, so it would perhaps have modes like "devtest" and "prodtest" and "fulltest", depending on the requirements.

Comment: i did not find usage of ${app.mode} in pom file including submodules. But yes i can see its used in spring.xml file. But i am wondering can pom supply paramater to spring ?

Answer (score 0):

If the property being set there isn't used anywhere else in the build (did you check any sub-modules?) then the answer to your question is "In this case it does nothing."

However, in general, setting a property like that will make it available later in the build in case you needed it for something.  If I had to guess, I'd say that this is the result of either an incomplete cleanup of code, or premature optimization.

Comment: i did not find usage of ${app.mode} in pom file including submodules. But yes i can see its used in spring.xml file. But i am wondering can pom supply paramater to spring ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectation is correct. Its used to pass on app.mode parameter to spring. See
[How can I use maven profile Id value in spring bean files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581151/how-can-i-use-maven-profile-id-value-in-spring-bean-files)

http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/