# How to mark failsafe plugin disabled by default in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have failsafe plugin configured in Maven, which runs integration tests as part of the build.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there anyway I can disable it by default and only enable it when I pass certain maven parameters to enable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use a Maven profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669258/how-does-one-use-a-maven-profile)

Comment: The configuration you have given is not needed because it's default. The default naming schema is to include `*IT.java` as integration test. Convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a profile and put the plugin within the profile tags.

Once you have used a profile, you can set special activation tags.

According to https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html:

Profiles can be automatically triggered based on the detected state of the build environment. These triggers are specified via an  section in the profile itself. Currently, **this detection is limited to prefix-matching of the JDK version, the presence of a system property or the value of a system property**.

The profile below will be activated when the system property "debug" is specified with any value:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
<activation>
  <property>
    <name>debug</name>
  </property>
</activation>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `skipITs` to `true` and enable the run by adding `-DskipITs=false` on command line.